How to fix mysql error: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
I'm learning web scrapping and the my current task involves saving the scrapped data to my database. I'm familiar with msyq.connector module in python and created seperate python environment for the project. I'm running on Kali Linux and by default mysql is installed so i started it with service start mysql created a user and run USE mysql command based on the following instructions. it opens mysql prompt and i can create a database and list the database i have. However when running scrapy crawl bookspider it result in the following error:
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'.
I've read through some solutions that i need to replace the 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' with 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci',  however i don't kwow which file to edit.
Lastly is there a difference between using mysql community server or mysql default software installed.
I read through the following solutions but i can't find the configuration file.

solution
solution


Check your MySQL version. You'd upgrade your MySQL to 8.x version.

Using mysql version 11.4.3 :


You use not MySQL but MariaDB which is different DBMS !!! Tags list fixed.

Thank you for the tags. So mysql that is provided by MariaDB and MySQL dbms are different?

So mysql that is provided by MariaDB and MySQL dbms are different? Of course. MariaDB was forked over 10 years ago, both servers have been developing independently since then, and now they just have a high compatibility.
